# pygame.mouse.get_pos() into two separate strings

Tags: python, pygame, cursor, coordinates, python-3.2

I'm using pygame and am using the code *pygame.mouse.get_pos()*, but need to turn this into two seperate strings: one where x = the x coordinate, and one where y = the y coordinate. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you tell us why you need to convert the mouse pos into a string?

Comment: To compare it to string variables X1, X2, Y1, and Y2, for a collision detection kind of thing

Comment: And why are those variables strings not ints or floats?

Comment: I'd like to see the code, because it seems to me that there's a better way to do the collision detection. But you should post it in a new question (if you can think of one) and not modifiy this post.

Comment: Thanks for the help skrx, i found Vinicius' answer really helpful though and now have it figured out.

Comment: I still recommend to post another question about your collision detection code. You shouldn't be using strings for collision detection, because strings are compared lexicographically and not like numbers (ints or floats), so it won't work correctly. Also, pygame has collision detection methods for [`pygame.Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint)s and [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide)s that will probably be faster and less error prone.

Comment: Ive been doing it a different way and I did realise the problem with using things, so am now using integers. And instead of using sprites i am using a set background and using the x, y coordinates of where the "wally" is to calculate if he has been hit. This way we can make the levels how we wanted to. I did put up another question about "a visual countdown python" and if you could help me with that part it would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.mouse.get_pos()` returns a tuple of two integers, x positions and y position:

```
>>> pygame.mouse.get_pos()
(413, 129)
```

You just need to creat two new strings based on these two values:

```
xpos_str = str(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0])
ypos_str = str(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1])
```

Comment: Thanks Vinicius, that really helped and I have it working now!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Comment: Ive almost finsihed my game now, i just need a countdown timer

Answer (score 1):

You can use map:

`x, y = map(str, pygame.mouse.get_pos())`

Comment: You don't need the lambda: `x, y = map(str, pygame.mouse.get_pos())`.